# https request from node server using client certificate reports expired certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I have a node server (v0.10.20) running on my local Windows 7 machine which makes https requests to a backend using my client certificate. The request worked in the beginning and from one day to another it stopped working with the error message:

```
[Error: 8432:error:14094415:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate
 expired:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1256:SSL alert number 45]
```

I did not change any coding and the certificate expiration date is in october 2015. Additionally, the https request still works if I fire it from the browser instead of letting nodejs do it. Does anyone know what the reason for this could be?

The relevant nodejs coding looks like this, even though I don't think the problem has to do with the coding. As I said, it stopped working without a change in the coding.

HTTPS request

```js
function callBackend(hostname, port, path, method, callback){
    var options = {
        hostname: hostname,
        port: port,
        path: path,
        method: method,
        pfx: SSOCertificate,
        passphrase: SSOCertificatePassphrase,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        strictSSL: false, 
    };

    var data = "";      
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) { data += chunk; });
        res.on('end', function(){ callback(data); });
    });

    req.end();
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

Certificate Retrieval. I already performed these steps manually and hardcoded the path to the final pfx file. The error stays the same

```js
if(process.platform == "win32") {
    exec("certutil -store -user -v my", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        var serialNumber = getSSOCertSerialNumber(error, stdout, stderr);
        var SSOCertificatePath = path.join(__dirname, '/SSOCert.pfx');

        exec("certutil -f -user -p " + SSOCertificatePassphrase + " -exportPFX " + serialNumber + " \"" + SSOCertificatePath + "\"", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            var SSOCertificate = fs.readFileSync(SSOCertificatePath);
            var deleteCommand = 'del "' + SSOCertificatePath + '"';
            callback(SSOCertificatePassphrase, SSOCertificate);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I did a mistake performing these steps manual. Together with the fact that certutil also returns "archived" certificates (which I could not see via the Windows UI) and a bug in handling the "Not After:" property returned by certutil, this caused the problem that we extracted a wrong certificate. The wrong certificate indeed expired one day ago.

So there was no problem with nodejs or the certificate itself, I just extracted the wrong certificate with certutil.